# Get the values of column if checkbox/radio box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how to get the values in a certain column if the checkbox or radio button on that particular row is checked. I've already started and came up with this:

```
    <script>
      var Step = <?php echo $_SESSION['Step'] ?>;
      if(Step == 3 || Step == 4 ) { setInterval(ScriptUpdate, 1000); }

      function ScriptUpdate()
      {
        if(Step == 3)
        {
          var checked = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
          var radioButtonSelectedCount = $(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked')).parent().filter(function() {return $(this).text().trim()=="Yes"}).length;
          var Counter = checked + radioButtonSelectedCount;
          $('#ES3I').text(Counter + ' Items');

          var price = 0;
          $("#TextBookTB tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(6)").each(function(td){
              var content = $(this).text();
              if($.isNumeric(content)) {
                price = price + Number(content);
                  console.log(price);
              }
          });
          $("#ES3P").text(price);
        }
      }
      </script>
```

The goal is that: when user checks the check box or answered 'yes' in the radio button it is the only time it will count the value. Apologies, I am really bad at jquery/javascript.

EDIT: html code as requested. The current output of the timer takes all of the values in all rows of that particular column.

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<input form="ES3S" type="radio" name="Textbook'.$i.'" value="'.$Result[$i]['ID'].'"> Yes
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input form="ES3S" type="radio" name="Textbook'.$i.'" value="-1">No
</label>


    <span class="d-inline-block" data-toggle="popover" title="Error" data-content="This book is required by the school. If you want to cancel this out, proceed to the principals office with the book for review." data-trigger="hover">
    <input form="ES3S" required checked onclick="return false;" type="checkbox" value="'.$Result[$i]['ID'].'" name="Textbook'.$i.'">
    </span>
```

Comment: What is the current outcome? What is going wrong?

Comment: Please post your HTML code.

Comment: added. @Script47 well the current output basically outputs data based on all rows of the specific column

Answer (score 0):

try this if you are using table

```
 var count = 0;
 $('#TABLEID').find('tr').each(function () {
                    var tableRow = $(this);
                    if (tableRow.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                        count += 1;

                    }
                });
```

Comment: this counts how many boxes are checked... not really showing which ones are checked and their values.. hmm..

Answer (score 0):

> when user checks the check box or answered 'yes' in the radio button it is the only time it will count the value

```js
$(function() {
  var selector = 'input[name^="Textbook"]';
  $(selector).on('click', function() {
    var checked = $(selector + ':checked').map(function() {
      return {
        'type': this.type,
        'value': this.value
      };
    }).get().filter(function(o) {
      return '-1' !== o.value; // skip if value = -1(No)
    });
    console.log('checked inputs', checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Textbook1" value="1"/>Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Textbook1" value="-1"/>No</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Textbook1" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Textbook2" value="2"/>Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Textbook2" value="-1"/>No</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Textbook2" value="2" />
</div>
```

Comment: This worked great but isn't exactly what i was after.. Since my radio buttons and checkboxes are in one column and the values i need are in another.. I need to be able to get the value of the (for example) column 6 when column 7's radio button is checked.. thanks (:

Comment: @DeathKing, have you tried this code with your script?